# Retrieve followeds shared posts sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this arrangement:

I want to retrieve all the posts shared by followers, bearing in mind those shared posts doesn't belong to another followed or the main follower,

**TABLE USERS**

```
id_user | name
15      Joe
16       Dan
17       Tom
    18        Ted
```

**TABLE COMMUNITY**

```
id_follower | followed  
15              16
15              17
```

**TABLE POSTS**

```
id_post | id_user | post    
    1       15          hi1     
    2       16          hi2    
    3       15          hi3   
    4       17          hi4      
    5       15          hi5   
    6       16          hi6   
    7       17          hi7  
    8       18          hi8   
    9       14          hi9
```

I'm adding up a new table "shares".

**TABLE SHARES**

```
id_sharer | id_post
16        4     
14        8 
17        8       
16        9
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT POSTS**

```
17        8  hi7 (shared by Tom)    
16        9  hi6  (shared by Dan)
```

How should it be the SQL query to get this new arrangement?

I was thinking of adding a line `LEFT JOIN shares l ON l.id_sharer=p.id_user`

```
SELECT p.*,
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id_user!=c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN shares l ON l.id_sharer=c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN community c ON c.id_followed!=p.id_user
WHERE c.id_follower=15
ORDER BY p.date_post DESC
```

*Tested but not retrieve as expected

Comment: Replace `WHERE` with `AND`...